# Termios error in docker container (while ros2 humble open manipulator piack and place importing)

Tags: c++, linux, ros

Hi i use docker container to develop in ros2 humble environment
While I was converting the open manipulator pick and place to ros2 humble in the container, I wrote the same code from the existing ros1 kinetic.

It's this part.

```
bool OMExample::kbhit()
{
  termios term;
  tcgetattr(0, &term);

  termios term2 = term;
  term2.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &term2);

  int byteswaiting;
  ioctl(0, FIONREAD, &byteswaiting);
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &term);
  printf("byteswaiting: %d\n", byteswaiting);
  return byteswaiting > 0;
}
```

This function returns Boolean value by checking whether a key has been pressed on the original keyboard, but it doesn't respond even if I keep pressing the key. Also, the value of 'byteswaiting' in the middle of printf also appears as 0.

Just in case, I'll leave a command when I run a docker container

```
sudo docker run --privileged -v /home/irasc-eunsung/humble_openmanipulator_4dof:/root/home -v /dev:/dev -it --network host --ipc host --pid host --volume /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY --name humble_openmanipulator_4dof --gpus all irasc/ros:humble-turtlebot3-desktop
```

```
bool OMExample::kbhit()
{
  pollfd fds;
  fds.fd = STDIN_FILENO; // Standard input
  fds.events = POLLIN;   // There is data to read

  // Check if input is available without waiting
  bool key_was_pressed = poll(&fds, 1, 0) > 0;

  // Print out the bool value
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << key_was_pressed << std::endl;

  return key_was_pressed;
}
```

i tried in this way,too. but nothing change.